# Seeking street/road shapefile with TF_TIME and FT_TIME attribute?

Tags: data, united-states

Doing a snow removal project within a county figuring out the fastest route for them to traverse on the roads to remove the snow from the sidewalk

I was able to find the roads/street shapefile for the county and using network analysis route analysis I was able to find the shortest distance for them to travel. The issue is the shapefile does not have a time or travel time attribute where I can know how long it takes for the travel the roads, because the shortest distance is not always the fastest time.

I looked on most government websites and even used the Tiger/Line shapefiles but they do not contain the time attributes.

Comment: Does your road fc have attributes for speed limit or road type.  You can create a time-cost based on that.

Comment: Maybe You could try to count it by yourself from your data using length and speed limit or average speed on different road types? Another option is to convert OSM data via som routing machine? If this could be resolution I could write more about it

Comment: @user3338197 yes the shapefile has attribute for speed limit and road type how would I create a time-cost based off of that

Comment: Rate * Time = Distance, so Time = Distance / Rate.  Just a thought, if they are removing snow, shouldn't they be driving below the speed limit, and most likely around the same speed on all roads? If so - shortest distance would suffice.

Comment: I would imagine if its like the ice routing we do, certain roads (ie residential) will be totally unpassable, and they are planning on hitting and navigating primarily by highways, arterials, etc...  anyway here are the tutorials on how to set that up  http://support.esri.com/EN/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/41176  and http://video.arcgis.com/watch/2110/creating-network-datasets-evaluators-for-time_dash_based-cost-attributes

Comment: How about OSM (open street map)? have you tried to download the data for your region and check for temporal fields>

Comment: Network Analyst will build Time by cost (you might need elevation too) see http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00470000005v000000

Comment: I suspect that this question may be just as on-topic at the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.